# Parar un Hilo - Thread que esté en ejecución

Tags: python, hilos, tkinter

Dentro de un programa, tengo una tarea que llama a un servicio web interno de la empresa. Mientras, se termina de ejecutarse u obtenerse el deseado resultado que viene de la llamada a ese servicio, permanece activo un Progressbar de Tkinter.

Esta sería la construcción e inicio del Thread

```
# encoding: utf-8

from Tkinter import *

# Hilos
import threading

# ...

anon_ini_accion = self.datos_a_xml
self._thread = threading.Thread()
self._thread.__init__(target=anon_ini_accion, args=())
self._thread.setDaemon(True)
self._thread.start()

# ...
```

He buscado por Internet para ver cómo se sabe si un hilo está, aún, en ejecución y/o cómo pararlo, también, y /o eliminarlo. O cómo hacer si se quisiera pararlo antes de que la tarea que tiene asignada termine, es decir, como cancelar la tarea y/o parar el hilo o destruirlo.

He visto este ejemplo por la web pero no sé si lo podría aplicar a mi caso o no sé si es de la versión que manejo o de la Python 3.X

```
def doit(stop_event, arg):
    while not stop_event.wait(1):
        print ("working on %s" % arg)
    print("Stopping as you wish.")


def main():
    pill2kill = threading.Event()
    t = threading.Thread(target=doit, args=(pill2kill, "task"))
    t.start()
    time.sleep(5)
    pill2kill.set()
    t.join()
```

Por ejemplo, lo del `stop_event` no sé si es propio de Python o es otra cosa, si tendría que ponerlo como parámetro de mi propio método, el que se llama para ejecutar la tarea que se asigna al hilo (en mi caso `self.datos_a_xml`) o qué.

Bueno, por otro lado, yo creía que cuando la tarea que tiene asignada el hilo finalizaba, el hilo dejaba de estar activo. Pero al comprobar esto

```
print 'self._thread.isAlive() >>', self._thread.isAlive()
```

me sigue dando `True` (aunque el proceso ya haya acabado parece que el hilo sigue viviendo ahí hasta el infinito :)).

Entonces, ¿como podría hacer, una vez iniciado el hilo (tras el `.start()` si quisiera parar el proceso o la ejecución de la tarea que tiene asignada? ¿cómo parar el hilo? O, igual, no es parar el término sino destruirlo. Bueno, lo que sea.

Si alguien tiene idea de cómo se podría hacer, sería de agradecer que me pusiera un ejemplo de ejecución.

Saludos.

NOTA: Python 2.7.X - Ubuntu - Tkinter 2.X

Comment: Probaste con Thread.exit() ??

Comment: Acá tenes varias soluciones útiles: https://code.i-harness.com/es/q/4f184

Comment: Un hilo en principio jamás debe ser detenido por la fuerza externamente, debe ser el propio hilo el que termine y de forma controlada (más aún si está procesando datos o sincronizado con otros hilos). Si se quiere forzar la terminación desde fuera, la forma correcta es como muestras, con un evento o cualquier otro método thread-safe. Ahora bien, la clave está en si tu método `anon_ini_accion` realiza su trabajo mediante un ciclo (`while` o `for`, da igual), en caso afirmativo podemos detener el hilo entre iteraciones de forma simple de forma segura.

Comment: Resumiendo, se carga un contenido textual, llamando al servicio a través del método guardado en `anon_ini_accion`, se inicia un proceso cuya primera acción es analizar el contenido y localizar, si existen, nombres de persona, lugares y otros. Luego, se efectúan otras acciones menos costosas. Mientras, el proceso dura, se ve una barra de progreso que desaparece cuando el proceso termina totalmente y se cargan los resultados. El caso es que la primera acción de localización de términos puede tardar mucho o incluso quedarte bloqueada. Por ello, la opción de darle al usuario que la pueda parar.

Comment: Y no @FJSevilla, no es un bloque `while` o `for` en su esencia principal.

Comment: Como comento un hilo no se puede detener externamente, esto no es algo exclusivo de Python de hecho. La idea es por tanto enviarle una señal que periódicamente en la función `target` o en el método `run` del hilo sea comprobada y de cumplirse termine. Claro, esto requiere que exista un punto en el que puedas hacer "if señal_terminar: salir" como se hace en el ejemplo que pones en el `while`.

Comment: Si esto es imposible (generalmente porque se depende de procesos o servicios externos que no podemos controlar) no intentes detener el hilo de otra forma, pasa de hilos y usa un proceso ([multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html)) que si se puede detener cuando se quiera (aunque hay que tener en cuenta posibles "efectos colaterales" como archivo corruptos porque se queda a la mitad en la escritura de uno, por ejemplo.)

Answer (score 0):

No soy un experto ni mucho menos, pero creo que hay varios problemas en tu código.
Lo primero, no tienes que llamar a .**init**, pues es lo primero que se ejecuta al llamar a .start()
Cada hilo (y cualquier otra clase, creo) debe tener como primer parámetro self, por ejemplo :

```
hilo(Thead):

    def __init__(self, sock, client):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.sock = sock
        self.chatClient = client
        self.finish = False

    while self.finish == False:
        # hace cosas
```

Lo primero que debe hacer .**init** es llamar a Thread.**init**(self)

Para crear un hilo solo haz:

```
if __name__ = "__main__":
    miSocket = socket.socket()
    miCliente = blabla

    miHilo = hilo(miSocket, miCliente)
    miHilo.start()
```

Nota que sólo pasamos 2 parámetros (en el ejemplo), pues el hilo ya se reconoce como primer argumento a sí mismo.

Para terminar el hilo solo tendrías que poner la bandera del hilo self.finish = True

```
miHilo.finish = True
```

Creo que eso sería suficiente.

No tengo muy claro si esto te ayuda, pero suerte.